# ASCII Character 62 Not Displaying Correctly in Superfish Menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, superfish

I am using the Superfish menu and for my menus that have sub-menus, I am using the character entity `&#62;`, which used to come up as ">"

I am using IE8 but for some reason, instead of the this greater than symbol appearing ">", I am now seeing two really small square boxes, side by side, in it's place.

Not sure why it's not display the HTML ASCII character for 62?

Unsure where I can show you an actual pic as I not sure where I can upload to.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you change &#62; to &gt; does anything different happen?

Comment: Do you explicitly specify a font? Or maybe your browser encoding is changed? I agree with @thirtydot however, try that first.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved based on @thirtydot's solution.